# Optimizing for loops, dataframe partition

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, optimization

I'm making an algorithm for feature selection in a binary classification which swipe through a `np.array` or `pd.series` to find intervals with good target division in a greedy approach.

The code works fine, However I use a `for` loop with a `if` conditional, so as a consequence the performance's quite slow. I was wondering if there's a smarter (and faster) way to do this. My code looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[51, 35, 1], [52, 3, 1], [53, 11, 1], [61, 8, 0], [75, 23, 0], [83, 45, 0], [95, 56, 1], [13, 66, 1], [1, 0, 1], [22, 68, 1]], columns=['feat1', 'feat2', 'target'])
target = df['target'] # values range from 0 to 1

def my_generic_metric_function(y):
  #This is just a generic metric that I'm using as an example.
  if len(y)>0:

    tgt = sum(y==1)
    no_tgt = sum(y==0)
    return 1.0*tgt/1.0*(no_tgt+tgt)

  else:
    return 0


def find_intervals(x, min_metric=10):
    ## Important: all my features receive a treatment that "fits" them in a range from 0 to 100
    ## Note that I'm not iterating through the DataFrame, I'm iterating over a range of values and finding the partitions in the dataframe.
    print(x.name)
    steps = [0]
    metric_partition = []
    for i in range(0, 101):


        ## This the target series filtered by the interval in x value
        band = target[(x>steps[-1]) & (x<=i)]
        partition_metric = my_generic_metric_function(band) 

        
        if partition_metric >= min_metric:
            steps.append(i)
            metric_partition.append(partition_metric)

    return {'f':x.name,'s': steps, 'm':metric_partition}
```

And I would apply this function to an entire dataframe using `.apply()`:

```
bi_df = df.drop("target", axis=1).apply(find_intervals)
```

This problem looks a lot like a CART algorithm, however I didn't find any implementation that could help me optimize my problem.

Comment: Is this some sort of implementation of [RandomForest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)?

Comment: Although is really similar for a greedy CART algorithm I'm actually building a **feature selection** and **categorisation** algorithm aimed for linear models (I expect to use this mainly with logistic regression).

Comment: What is the purpose of the my_generic_function function? It has some errors.

Comment: The idea is this metric is used to evaluate the quality of the cut, I'm using this metric just as an example. If some interval has this metric higher than a threshold (in this example 1.2) it would append the current `i` value from the iterator to the `steps` list and the generic metric value at `metric_partition` list to evaluate the next possible interval. The real metric that I'm using's a little bit more complicated, and calculating it *doesn't* have high time consumption, so I just replaced this real metric with a "generic" function.

Comment: When I run as-is I get a `KeyError: '[1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1] not found in axis'`.  
It seems that the apply line should be adjusted for: `bi_df = df.drop("target", axis=1).apply(find_intervals)`.  
But then it returns a `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero` on `return tgt / (no_tgt + tgt)`. Can you confirm?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment, I reviewed my code, added one more column and fixed some minor bugs, now is working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `my_generic_metric_function` is a monotonically increasing function in respect to `i` in the loop. I may not be able to prove it right now, but I've done few simulations with random numbers and all had this results.
If this is the case, instead of doing a linear search (`for i in range(0, 101)`) you can do a (almost) binary search looking for the first number to reach your min_metric threshold.
It would be almost as a simple binary search but as a second verification step you would need to check if the number that came before is less then the threshold.
This would reduce the loop time from n to log(n).

Besides that you can try to [index your feature columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

Other options could be try to use numpy instead of pandas for everything, [adjust and compile](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html) `find_interval` and even parallelize each column apply (with multiprocessing or other simple approach). But these three won't reduce your algorithm time, just improve the execution time (although for some operations numpy performance is orders of magnitude better then pandas).